# Powershell Get Hashtable Values

Tags: powershell

I've got this Hashtable with this values:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                                            
Bayas_palm_stem_A0311.jpg      1                                                                                                                
Bayas_palm_stem_A0312.jpg      2                                                                                                                
Bukit_Bangkong_area.tiff       1                                                                                                                
BY_and_siblings_A0259.jpg      5                                                                                                                
Cassava_camp_A0275.jpg         1                                                                                                                
Children_A0115.jpg             6                                                                                                                
cip_barau_kubak.jpg            1
```

How can i get only the Name and Value where Value is greater than 1 ?

I'm tryng with this code, but i'm doing something wrong!!!

```
$RT | Group-Object Name , Value | Where-Object {$RT.Values -gt 1}
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$hashtable.GetEnumerator()` to enumerate the *individual* name-value pairs in the hashtable:

```bsh
$RT.GetEnumerator() |Where-Object {$_.Value -gt 1}
```

Beware that if you assign the resulting pairs to a variable, it's not longer a hashtable - it's just an array of individual name-value pairs.

To create a new hashtable with only the name-value pairs that filter through, do:

```bsh
$RTFiltered = @{}
$RT.GetEnumerator() |Where-Object {$_.Value -gt 1} |ForEach-Object {$RTFiltered.Add($_.Name, $_.Value)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$RT.getenumerator() | Where-Object {$_.Value -gt 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Hashtable defined like this.

```
$rt = @{
"Bayas_palm_stem_A0311.jpg " =     1                                                                                                             
"Bayas_palm_stem_A0312.jpg " =     2                                                                                                               
"Bukit_Bangkong_area.tiff  " =     1                                                                                                              
"BY_and_siblings_A0259.jpg " =     5                                                                                                             
"Cassava_camp_A0275.jpg    " =     1                                                                                                            
"Children_A0115.jpg        " =     6
"cip_barau_kubak.jpg       " =     1
}
```

You can call `GetEnumerator()` which allows you to iterate through the Hashtable.

Once you've got an enumeration of the members, then your normal PowerShell value comparisons will work.

You can get values greater than 1 like this:

```
$rt.GetEnumerator() | ? Value -gt 1

Name                           Value                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                            
BY_and_siblings_A0259.jpg      5                                                                                                
Children_A0115.jpg             6                                                                                                
Bayas_palm_stem_A0312.jpg      2
```